# Trying to check a String number against Range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a situation where my data is a number, and is saved as a String.  I have a Range that I want to check the String against.  The item in the Range is an Integer.  How can I do this?  Below is my code for the scope I am writing:

```
if value == "above"
  scope.where(["level > ?", level_range.last])
elsif value == "below"
  scope.where(["level < ?", level_range.first])
elsif value == "at"
  scope.where(:level => level_range)
else
  scope
end
```

Comment: Use `to_i`? I'm confused.

Comment: I am not sure exactly how to use `.to_i`.  I am using the SQL statement "level > ?` and I can't just plug in the `.to_i` without it throwing me an error that there is no column level.to_i.  It seems like I am overlooking something obvious, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Are you saying that the `level` in `"level > ?"` is a `:string` column? If so, you would need to change this column to a numeric type, such as `:integer`. The database can't compare values numerically if they are stored as strings.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct.  I was afraid this might be the case.  I was just trying to see if there was any other way that I had overlooked.

Comment: You could cast the string inside the database but the syntax is database specific. Why are you storing a number in a string column?

Comment: Using `change_column` in a migration to convert the column type to `:integer` should work, as long as all of the values you currently have stored in that column are actually string representations of integers (and not, say, "foobar" or "2.56"). It may depend on the database engine, though, so I would test this on a copy of your database that you don't mind getting messed up.

Comment: Originally the data in this column was based on letters, so it had to be a string.  A recent change forced everything to numbers, and hence the integer range.  I ended up running a migration to change the column to an integer after making sure all of the data was clean.  It worked.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say the `level` numbers are stored as strings. First of all, that's kinda dumb; if you can, fix your schema to store as numeric.  If you can't change the schema, and your db is ANSI compliant, you can use [`CAST()`](http://users.atw.hu/sqlnut/sqlnut2-chp-4-sect-4.html#ch04-_Toc484079582) on the stored value to perform integer comparisons with your range parameters.

```
if value == "above"
  scope.where(["CAST(level AS INTEGER) > ?", level_range.last])
elsif value == "below"
  scope.where(["CAST(level AS INTEGER) < ?", level_range.first])
elsif value == "at"
  scope.where(["CAST(level AS INTEGER) BETWEEN ? AND ?",
              level_range.first, level_range.last])
else
  scope
end
```

One caveat is that the behaviour of CAST if the string is not a valid integer representation is to throw an error; this is another good reason to type your data correctly in the schema.

Comment: Originally the data in this column was based on letters, so it had to be a string.  A recent change forced everything to numbers, and hence the integer range.  I ended up running a migration to change the column to an integer after making sure all of the data was clean.